# How to free a union array in C?

Tags: c, free, unions

I have a function that return me a union array, I need to free a union array  after I use it.

An updated code :

This is a struct

```
typedef union _data {
    float F;
    uint8_t  B[4];
} floatCharFunction;
```

This is a Read Function:

```
void HW_SWversion(version state,floatCharFunction* ver)
{
  floatCharFunction fVersionRead[2] = {0,0};//SW-HW
  *ver = *fVersionRead;
  //floatCharFunction SW,HW;
  if(state == SAVE_VERSION)
  {
    FLASH_ERASE(_4KB,VERSION_BASE_ADDR);    
    fVersionRead[0].F =VERSION_SW;
    fVersionRead[01].F =VERSION_HW;
    FLASH_WRITE(fVersionRead[0].B,VERSION_BASE_ADDR,VERSION_SIZE_IN_BYTES/2);
    FLASH_WRITE(fVersionRead[1].B,VERSION_BASE_ADDR+VERSION_SIZE_IN_BYTES/2,VERSION_SIZE_IN_BYTES/2);
  }else if(state == READ_VERSION)
  {
    FLASH_READ(VERSION_BASE_ADDR,fVersionRead[0].B, VERSION_SIZE_IN_BYTES/2);
    FLASH_READ(VERSION_BASE_ADDR+VERSION_SIZE_IN_BYTES/2,fVersionRead[1].B, VERSION_SIZE_IN_BYTES/2);
    //u16VersionRead = (versions[0] << 8) | versions[1];


  }else return;
}
```

This is a Main :

```
main()
{
  floatCharFunction* ver = malloc(2*sizeof(*ver));
if (ver == NULL) {
   //printf("out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION,ver);
free(ver);
}
```

Comment: You do not need any `malloc` here.

Comment: i tried free(ver);
But i still see a array in memory with the versions numbers

Comment: `free(ver)` works, but the malloc should be moved to `HW_SWversion()` body.

Comment: Btw, I don't think freeing an array will erase this content: it just flags the memory as available but as long as you don't overwrite it you will still see your data in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- `ver = HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION);` reassigns `ver`, leaking the memory you allocated in the previous line
- `HW_SWversion` returns a pointer to an automatic variable that immediately goes out of scope.  Consequences of accessing this variable are undefined.

The easiest change here would be to change `HW_SWversion` to update a pointer to a client allocated instance.

```
void HW_SWversion(version state, floatCharFunction* ver)
{
    /* assign version info */
}

int main()
{
    floatCharFunction ver[2];
    HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION, &ver);
}
```

Or, if you want to use dynamically allocated memory

```
void HW_SWversion(version state, floatCharFunction* ver)
{
    /* assign version info */
}

int main()
{
    floatCharFunction* ver = malloc(2*sizeof(*ver));
    if (ver == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION, ver);
    free(ver);
}
```

Comment: Error[Pe167]: argument of type "union _data **" is incompatible with parameter of type "union _data *" \

Comment: HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION, &ver);//ERROR

Comment: For the second case, wouldn't it make more sense to have `HW_SWversion()` do the allocation and return the new pointer?

Comment: @user3428151 I've fixed a typo in the second snippet and omitted the implementation of `HW_SWversion` (I presume you know how this should work much better than me)

Comment: @unwind I have a slight preference for the current form as it supports clients using either dynamic or automatic allocation.  If you view it as purely an example of dynamic allocation then I agree that the `malloc` should move

Comment: In the function this is not works?
  floatCharFunction fVersionRead[2] = {0};//SW-HW
  *ver = *fVersionRead;
Why>?

Comment: Hi i updated my codes , can you please review it? why the answer is not return well?

Comment: The line `*ver = *fVersionRead` is before you assign version info to `fVersionRead`.  You should either move this line to the end of the function or (better) just assign directly to `ver` instead

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, the

```
floatCharFunction fVersionRead[2];//SW-HW
```

Is a local variable and usage:

```
ver = HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION);
```

In this case is an **undefined behavior** because `fVersionRead` is allocated **on stack**. No one guarantees that result will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Decide, stack or heap? (but not both)

```
/* Stack (Note static) */
static floatCharFunction fVersionRead[2]; //SW-HW
floatCharFunction *pVersion = fVersionRead;
return pVersion;

/* Heap */
floatCharFunction *ver  = (floatCharFunction *)malloc(2*sizeof(floatCharFunction));
```

The keyword `static` extends the lifetime of a variable outside the function.

If you go for stack don't call `free`, else `free(ver);` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to free an union array after i use it.

by the time you even get to using it, the array is already "freed". Since it's a **local** variable with automatic storage duration, it goes out of scope and is deallocated when the function returns. So, you are using a pointer to a nonexistent object, so your code currently invokes undefined behavior.

You'd be better off `malloc()`ing the array and returning a pointer to its first element. Then, of course, you will need to `free()` it (just like in your code) afterwards.

But I'm sure any introductory C book could have shown you this.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code are::

- You are `malloc`ing some memory for `floatCharFunction` in your `main`.
- You are not giving this memory to your `HW_SWversion` to populate or modify.
- You are using some memory for `floatCharFunction` on stack in your `HW_SWversion`, 
  scope:: local to `HW_SWversion`.
- You are returning the memory address of an automatic variable.
- The local variable goes out-of-scope as soon as `HW_SWversion` exits.
- You are trying to `free` that out-of-scope memory which will cause **Undefined Behaviour**.
- Your `malloc`ed memory pointer value is lost, so memory leak.

Solution::

Either do not use `malloc` and pass the memory as parameter to `HW_SWversion` like this::

```
void HW_SWversion(version state, floatCharFunction* ver)
{
    *ver = /* assign version info */
}

int main()
{
    floatCharFunction ver[2];
    HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION, &ver);
}
```

OR

If you want to use dynamic allocation::

```
floatCharFunction* HW_SWversion(version state)
{
  floatCharFunction *pVersion = malloc(2*sizeof(floatCharFunction));
  return pVersion;
}

main()
{
//
  floatCharFunction *ver = HW_SWversion(READ_VERSION);
  free (ver) ;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try this 
free(ver)

the system remembers the memory location of ver, and knows the size of memory of the this ptr holds

Comment: No...ver is reassigned. It doesn't points to malloced memory anymore.

Comment: I did not downvote, but avoid answers including may, try etc. If you are unsure, try it, analyze it and then answer.